# How to break if/else statement in JavaScript once a condition is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, redirect

So I have this basic JavaScript code to detect a user language and redirect to the proper page based on the browser language, the issue I am facing is that the if/else statement keeps going as an infinite loop and the browser keeps refreshing.

The code is set on a separate file and is included only in the en-US page, the code is a stand-alone, not using any function.

```
if(userLang == "en-US"){
  window.location.href = "domainame.com/faq.html";
}
else if(userLang == "nl"){
  window.location.href = "domainame.com/faq-de.html";
}
else if(userLang == "fr"){
  window.location.href = "domainame.com/faq-fr.html";
}
else if(userLang == "es-ES"){
  window.location.href = "domainame.com/faq-es.html";
}
else if(userLang == "ja"){
  window.location.href = "domainame/faq-ja.html";
}
```

I expect the browser to check for the user language and redirect to the proper page, instead, the browser keeps refreshing.

Comment: Do you have this code in all the pages?

Comment: `domainame.com/faq-de.html` etc needs a schema, else its looks for folder.

Comment: How these if/else statements are being used ? are the inside any function ?

Comment: As an example, if this code is in the `faq.html`, and the user language is detected as `en-US`, of course it's going to keep looping. It's possible to stop the loop with, say, cookies, but any of those redirection targets shouldn't also have that code. edit: I guess all you need to do is remove the `en-US` redirect, since you don't have to redirect away from `faq.html` in that case anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra check to only change the page if it is not the current page.

Something like this:

```
let lanPage = '';
if(userLang == "en-US"){
  lanPage = "https://domainame.com/faq.html";
} else if(userLang == "nl"){
  lanPage = "https://domainame.com/faq-de.html";
} else if(userLang == "fr"){
  lanPage = "https://domainame.com/faq-fr.html";
} else if(userLang == "es-ES"){
  lanPage = "https://domainame.com/faq-es.html";
} else if(userLang == "ja"){
  lanPage = "https://domainame/faq-ja.html";
}

if(lanPage && lanPage !== location.href) {
  location.href = lanPage;
}
```